# How to customize the given validation on GWT datebox?

Tags: date, validation, gwt, customization

I want to create a validation date box in GWT that will change the background color of datebox to red when the date is null or not in **yyyy-mm-dd** format. It must be work fine if we type the date from keyboard or we take it from date picker.

Note - By default when no date is there on date box the background of datebox must be set to red

Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can style the `DateBox` by defining a CSS class to make the background red and applying it using `.addStyleName()` and `.removeStyleName()`.

You can track the value in the `DateBox` by defining a `ValueChangeHandler` and `DateBox.addValueChangeHandler()`.